# Zero-Variance Removal

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

I want to remove sensors which appear to have no variance? I removed all sensors with a temperature=0, and can sort by date/day of the week, but further errors within the data have came to light. Some sensors have a string of temperature recordings of 4.5 and 7.3 with no change across many days. I was reproducible code so don't want to simply remove 4.5 and 7.3 values

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([[A, 2.045], [A, 3.056], [B, 6], [B, 6], columns=['Sen', 'Temp'])
```

`In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
   Sen Temp
0  A  2.045
1  A  3.056
2  B  6
3  B  6`

So I have grouped the data using basic group and sort functions to get a simple output as above. However. I want to remove all "B" sensors from df.Sen as the variance of values within df.Temp for B equals 0. I'm getting confused just typing this out but is this possible? I was thinking of creating a new column based on a variance calculation and deleting that way, but is there a simpler solution?

`Out[2]: 
   Sen Temp
0  A  2.045
1  A  3.05`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby().transform()` to mask the variance:

```
df[df.groupby('Sen').Temp.transform('var') > 0]
```

Output:

```
  Sen   Temp
0   A  2.045
1   A  3.056
```

However, this might fail if you have some groups with only one valid data point. On the other hand, since variance `0` means only one value across the group, you can use `nunique`:

```
df[df.groupby('Sen').Temp.transform('nunique') > 1]
```